# Groovy invokes adb command to pull a file but the new file is invisible

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

**My Situation**

I am learning `gradle plugin` and `groovy`. Now I need to invoke `adb` command to pull a file from my device and then I will operate this new file on my PC.

```
def command = 'adb pull /sdcard/com.hackerli.sample.trace ./'
['bash','-c',command].execute()
// now I list all file
println(['bash','-c','ls'].execute())
```

**My Problem**

When I first execute above script, `ls` does not display the new file. The second time executed, it appears. I guess that the file directory does not refresh. So how can I do with it while I need to operate the new file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the first process to finish:

```
def command = 'adb pull /sdcard/com.hackerli.sample.trace ./'
['bash','-c',command].execute().waitFor()

println(['bash','-c','ls'].execute())
```

Comment: It works like a charm.Thank you very much.Wish you a best day